# I don't understand how paintComponent works in Java

Tags: java, image, swing, jframe, paintcomponent

I'm new in Java and currently my level is around printing text. Even though, I wanted to start with graphical content but sadly I didn't be able to do it.

I began with JFrame and everything went well but when I had to print images I had problem. Thanks to YouTube I could copy this piece of code where shows clearly (not enough for me, though) how to print an image in a JFrame.

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Main extends JPanel{

  public static void main(String[] args){

    JFrame j = new JFrame("Image");

    j.setSize(1080,720);

    j.setVisible(true);

    j.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    j.add(new Main());

  }

   public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

    super.paintComponent(g);

    ImageIcon i = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Hello\\Pictures\\picture.jpg");

    i.paintIcon(this, g, 0, 0);

   }

}
```

I honestly don't understand that. I looked for explanations on internet but no answer has really helped me out. What I don't comprehend is basically `j.add(new Main())` (are we linking the same class?) and `paintComponent(Graphics g)`...

Comment: If that Youtube poster has more videos, you would do well to avoid them because he has some glaring problems in that code: 

1. He's reading in an image file in the paintComponent method, something is unnecessarily wasteful (why read it in more than once?) and something that can slow a GUI's graphics to a crawl and thus something that should **never** be done. 
2. He's also creating an ImageIcon where only an Image such as a BufferedImage is needed or desired.

Comment: As to "how paintComponent works", that's a **very** broad subject to answer in the confines of this site. Best for you to look at better tutorials which you can find here for basic info:  [Lesson: Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html), and for more advanced info:  [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html).

Comment: As for `j.add(new Main())`, you here are creating a Main object which **is** a JPanel, and adding it to `j`, a `JFrame`, top level window that is then displayed. Note that the main method has another error -- `setVisible(true)` should be called on the JFrame only **after** all components have been added. Otherwise there's risk that some components might not be displayed.

Comment: Note also that you will rarely if ever call the `paintComponent(...)` method directly. Instead the JVM (the Java Virtual Machine -- the code that runs your Java program on your computer) will call it, and when it calls it will be only partially under your control. By calling `setVisible(true)` on the JFrame, the GUI is displayed and all added component's painting methods will be called. By calling `repaint()` on a GUI, you are requesting that all painting methods be called, and they usually will be, but it's not a guarantee. Also the OS may request that they be called.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think I've seen so many errors in a supposed teaching example.

Here's the rewritten code.  You have to put the image in the same directory as the Java code to read the image.

```
package com.ggl.testing;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class DrawImage implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame j = new JFrame("Image");
        j.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        j.add(new ImagePanel(getImage()));

        j.pack();
        j.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        j.setVisible(true);
    }

    private Image getImage() {
        try {
            return ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream(
                    "StockMarket.png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new DrawImage());
    }

    public class ImagePanel extends JPanel {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = -2668799915861031723L;

        private Image image;

        public ImagePanel(Image image) {
            this.image = image;
            this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(image.getWidth(null), image
                    .getHeight(null)));
        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
        }

    }

}
```

Here are the important concepts to take from this code.

1. Always start a Java Swing application with a call to the SwingUtilities invokeLater method.  This puts the creation and updates of the Swing components on the [Event Dispatch thread (EDT)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).
2. As others have mentioned, read the images before you try and display them.  This code will abend if the image is missing.  This code will also work when you package your Java class in a JAR file, along with the image.
3. You don't set any sizes.  You let the JFrame and JPanels calculate their own sizes using [Swing layouts](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).  In this particular example, the JPanel takes on the size of the image you read, and the JFrame is just large enough to hold the image JPanel.
4. You use Swing components.  You only extend a Swing component when you want to override a method in the class.  In this example, we used a JFrame and extended a JPanel.

Comment: Why is Java that complicated? I just want to print an image out on a window and all I have to do is that. I'm a beginner and I find this language completely difficult.

Comment: @Arnau:  You're correct.  Java is complicated to learn, because you can create so many different applications using Java.  Java Swing has rules, and once you learn the rules, you are free to be creative.